# reduce line-height between two i-elements

Tags: css

I have an issue with the line-height. Is there a way to reduce the line-height and move the i-elements closer so at least the petrol-background touch since it's not possible to use a negative value for line-height?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1c6m8ao/2/)

HTML:

```
<i>Nummer eins</i><br>
<i>Nummer zwei</i>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic);

i {
font-family: "Lora", serif;
font-size: 0.8em;       
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 0em;
padding: 0px 3px;
color: white;
background-color: #406A76;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if this resolve your issue [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1c6m8ao/3/)

html

```
<i>Nummer eins</i>  //  iremoved the br tag
<i>Nummer zwei</i>
```

css

```
i {  // line height removed
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #406A76;
  float: left;    //added float left here 
  clear: both;   //added clear both
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally solved my issue. Just a question: why is it necessary to remove the line-height?

Comment: @ris OP said with br tag he is not able to touch both i element but what you did is put them in one row..he din ask for that..check back and m confused why op asked as ans?

Comment: then why he used??and then what is the issue..to get both i element in one row? and no one will give upvote to that simple question..there is something wrong..

Comment: issue was br tag and line height . I mensioned this in my answer .

Comment: First of all, I'm a woman. Second, I added a <br> because I didn't wanted them in a row, which ris solved by geting rid of the <br> and let the elements float left! My issue was solved perfectly. I'm a bit confused – the only thing that's "wrong" is that I didnt come up with that solution on my own. P.S. what does "asked as ans" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to eliminate the white bar between the two lines, it might be a good solution to put them both in a `<div>` or `<span>` (I used a span)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1c6m8ao/5/)

html

```
<span>
<i>Nummer eins</i><br>
<i>Nummer zwei</i>
</span>
```

css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic);

i {
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;       
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 0em;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #406A76;
}
span {
     background-color: #406A76;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Might depend on the browser, I'm using Firefox 37.0.1.

Comment: I am using a slightly older version, but it still should work :|

Comment: you just add the same color in the span . which doesn't solve the issue . it will increase the height of element .